# Subclassing UIPickerView and add UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I'm trying to create subclass of UIPickerView and add UIToolbar above the picker.
I've read several posting here and there, but I found most recommend that create a view and add picker and toolbar on it. (Or use UIActionSheet)

Here's what I've tried so far.

CU_PICKERView is the subclass of UIPickerView
I tried to use the inputView and inputAccessoryView which are already properties of pickerview

```
@interface CU_PICKERView : UIPickerView
@property (strong, readwrite) UIView * inputView;
@property (strong, readwrite) UIView * inputAccessoryView;

-(void)showWithAnimation:(BOOL)flag;
-(void)hideWithAnimation:(BOOL)flag;
@end
```

Below is the CU_PICKERView.m

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setToolbar];
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setToolbar
{
    _toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [_toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

    UIBarButtonItem * btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(barbtnPressed:)];
    [btnCancel setTag:TOOLBAR_BTN_CANCEL];
    [btnCancel setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];

    NSArray * btnArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:btnCancel, nil];
    [_toolbar setItems:btnArray];

    self.inputAccessoryView = _toolbar;
    self.inputView = self;
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return true;
}

-(void)barbtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    TOOLBAR_TAG tag = [sender tag];
    switch (tag) {
        case TOOLBAR_BTN_CANCEL:
        {
            [self hideWithAnimation:YES];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

From here is the odd point. I created a instance of CU_PickerView as usual.

OtherViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setPicker];
}

-(void)setPicker
{
    _picker = [[CU_PICKERView alloc] init];
    [_picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:_picker];
}
```

It seems that it worked perfectly. The showWithAnimation and hideWithAnimation worked nicely.

I created a button on the OtherViewController and tried to use the button to create and show the CUPICKERView. I just moved the setPicker method to a button event handler, but it didn't work. I can't let the inputAccessoryView showed.

I tried to call [_picker becomeFirstResponder] but it didn't work.

Is there anything I'm missing about the inputAccessoryView?

- I soleved it. Invoke the setPicker in viewDidLoad and hide it in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Here's what I found so far. When I call setPicker in viewDidLoad, the picker's super view is UIPeripheralHostView even I added the picker on self.view. However I call the setPicker other than viewDidLoad(like the button event handler), it's superview is self.view. I can't understand why...

Comment: If you found the answer, you can post it as an answer and then accept it. That way when other people look at it, they can see it has been solved (and possibly even use your answer for their own problems).

Comment: I`m not sure that it is a correct solution for this. After several tests, I'll answer with more detail code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Now I figure out why many people recommend to create a view and add picker&toolbar on it.

After several tests, using USPeripheralHostView is more complex than just using the view(picker+toolbar). And I'm not sure that it's allowed by Apple.